# Upgrading extended webservice endpoints to System Contract 3 (18.200.001) throws error "View Results has BQL delegate"

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

We have an EDI vendor that uses our extended webservice endpoints.  These are currently all still 6.1 Contract 2.

We attempted to provide upgraded 18.200.001 Contract 3 endpoints, but they are running into an error "View Results has BQL delegate" when trying to pull data from the endpoint.  (The endpoint gathers a large amount of inventory data via GI.)

The vendor tells us that if these are extended rather than default they should continue to work even after the old default versions are deprecated.

They also say: With 2018 Acumatica updated their optimization making almost impossible to pull entire record sets as these queries do. There may be a way to turn off the BQL delegate but you would need to consult Acumatica for that.

Is this true? Are we better off leaving them as is, or is there a way of making them work for the new contract?

Below is the (upgraded) GI the webservice endpoint uses.

```
<GenericInquiryScreen>
    <data-set>
        <relations format-version="3" relations-version="20180809" main-table="GIDesign" stable-sharing="True" file-name="(Name)">
            <link from="GIFilter (DesignID)" to="GIDesign (DesignID)" />
            <link from="GIGroupBy (DesignID)" to="GIDesign (DesignID)" />
            <link from="GIMassAction (DesignID)" to="GIDesign (DesignID)" />
            <link from="GIMassUpdateField (DesignID)" to="GIDesign (DesignID)" />
            <link from="GINavigationScreen (DesignID)" to="GIDesign (DesignID)" />
            <link from="GINavigationParameter (DesignID, ScreenID)" to="GINavigationScreen (DesignID, ScreenID)" />
            <link from="GIOn (DesignID, RelationNbr)" to="GIRelation (DesignID, LineNbr)" />
            <link from="GIRecordDefault (DesignID)" to="GIDesign (DesignID)" />
            <link from="GIRelation (DesignID, ParentTable)" to="GITable (DesignID, Alias)" />
            <link from="GIRelation (DesignID, ChildTable)" to="GITable (DesignID, Alias)" />
            <link from="GIResult (DesignID)" to="GIDesign (DesignID)" />
            <link from="GIResult (ObjectName, DesignID)" to="GITable (Alias, DesignID)" />
            <link from="GISort (DesignID)" to="GIDesign (DesignID)" />
            <link from="GITable (DesignID)" to="GIDesign (DesignID)" />
            <link from="GIWhere (DesignID)" to="GIDesign (DesignID)" />
            <link from="SiteMap (Url)" to="GIDesign (DesignID)" type="WeakByUrl" linkname="toDesignById" baseurl="~/GenericInquiry/GenericInquiry.aspx" paramnames="id" />
            <link from="SiteMap (Url)" to="GIDesign (Name)" type="WeakByUrl" linkname="toDesignByName" baseurl="~/GenericInquiry/GenericInquiry.aspx" />
            <link from="ListEntryPoint (ListScreenID)" to="SiteMap (ScreenID)" />
            <link from="SiteMap (ScreenID)" to="GIDesign (PrimaryScreenIDNew)" linkname="to1Screen" />
            <link from="SiteMap (NodeID)" to="SiteMap (ParentID)" type="WeakToParent" recursive-nesting="yes" include-parents="False" />
            <link from="FilterHeader (ScreenID)" to="SiteMap (ScreenID)" />
            <link from="FilterRow (FilterID)" to="FilterHeader (FilterID)" />
            <link from="PivotTable (NoteID)" to="FilterHeader (RefNoteID)" />
            <link from="PivotField (ScreenID, PivotTableID)" to="PivotTable (ScreenID, PivotTableID)" />
            <link from="MUIScreen (NodeID)" to="SiteMap (NodeID)" />
            <link from="MUIWorkspace (WorkspaceID)" to="MUIScreen (WorkspaceID)" type="FromMaster" linkname="workspaceToScreen" split-location="yes" updateable="True" />
            <link from="MUISubcategory (SubcategoryID)" to="MUIScreen (SubcategoryID)" type="FromMaster" updateable="True" />
            <link from="MUITile (ScreenID)" to="SiteMap (ScreenID)" />
            <link from="MUIWorkspace (WorkspaceID)" to="MUITile (WorkspaceID)" type="FromMaster" linkname="workspaceToTile" split-location="yes" updateable="True" />
            <link from="MUIArea (AreaID)" to="MUIWorkspace (AreaID)" type="FromMaster" updateable="True" />
            <link from="MUIPinnedScreen (NodeID, WorkspaceID)" to="MUIScreen (NodeID, WorkspaceID)" type="WeakIfEmpty" isEmpty="Username" />
            <link from="MUIFavoriteWorkspace (WorkspaceID)" to="MUIWorkspace (WorkspaceID)" type="WeakIfEmpty" isEmpty="Username" />
            <link from="GIDesign (NoteID)" to="Note (NoteID)" type="Note" />
            <link from="GIFilter (NoteID)" to="Note (NoteID)" type="Note" />
            <link from="GIFilter (NoteID)" to="GIFilterKvExt (RecordID)" type="RowKvExt" />
            <link from="GIGroupBy (NoteID)" to="Note (NoteID)" type="Note" />
            <link from="GIOn (NoteID)" to="Note (NoteID)" type="Note" />
            <link from="GIRelation (NoteID)" to="Note (NoteID)" type="Note" />
            <link from="GIResult (NoteID)" to="Note (NoteID)" type="Note" />
            <link from="GIResult (NoteID)" to="GIResultKvExt (RecordID)" type="RowKvExt" />
            <link from="GISort (NoteID)" to="Note (NoteID)" type="Note" />
            <link from="GITable (NoteID)" to="Note (NoteID)" type="Note" />
            <link from="GIWhere (NoteID)" to="Note (NoteID)" type="Note" />
            <link from="FilterHeader (NoteID)" to="Note (NoteID)" type="Note" />
        </relations>
        <layout>
            <table name="GIDesign">
                <table name="GIFilter" uplink="(DesignID) = (DesignID)">
                    <table name="Note" uplink="(NoteID) = (NoteID)" />
                    <table name="GIFilterKvExt" uplink="(NoteID) = (RecordID)" />
                </table>
                <table name="GIGroupBy" uplink="(DesignID) = (DesignID)">
                    <table name="Note" uplink="(NoteID) = (NoteID)" />
                </table>
                <table name="GIMassAction" uplink="(DesignID) = (DesignID)" />
                <table name="GIMassUpdateField" uplink="(DesignID) = (DesignID)" />
                <table name="GINavigationScreen" uplink="(DesignID) = (DesignID)">
                    <table name="GINavigationParameter" uplink="(DesignID, ScreenID) = (DesignID, ScreenID)" />
                </table>
                <table name="GIRecordDefault" uplink="(DesignID) = (DesignID)" />
                <table name="GISort" uplink="(DesignID) = (DesignID)">
                    <table name="Note" uplink="(NoteID) = (NoteID)" />
                </table>
                <table name="GITable" uplink="(DesignID) = (DesignID)">
                    <table name="GIRelation" uplink="(DesignID, Alias) = (DesignID, ParentTable)">
                        <table name="GIOn" uplink="(DesignID, LineNbr) = (DesignID, RelationNbr)">
                            <table name="Note" uplink="(NoteID) = (NoteID)" />
                        </table>
                        <table name="Note" uplink="(NoteID) = (NoteID)" />
                    </table>
                    <table name="GIResult" uplink="(Alias, DesignID) = (ObjectName, DesignID)">
                        <table name="Note" uplink="(NoteID) = (NoteID)" />
                        <table name="GIResultKvExt" uplink="(NoteID) = (RecordID)" />
                    </table>
                    <table name="Note" uplink="(NoteID) = (NoteID)" />
                </table>
                <table name="GIWhere" uplink="(DesignID) = (DesignID)">
                    <table name="Note" uplink="(NoteID) = (NoteID)" />
                </table>
                <table name="SiteMap" uplink="(DesignID) = (Url)" recursion="(NodeID) = (ParentID)" linkname="toDesignById">
                    <table name="ListEntryPoint" uplink="(ScreenID) = (ListScreenID)" />
                    <table name="FilterHeader" uplink="(ScreenID) = (ScreenID)">
                        <table name="FilterRow" uplink="(FilterID) = (FilterID)" />
                        <table name="PivotTable" uplink="(RefNoteID) = (NoteID)">
                            <table name="PivotField" uplink="(ScreenID, PivotTableID) = (ScreenID, PivotTableID)" />
                        </table>
                        <table name="Note" uplink="(NoteID) = (NoteID)" />
                    </table>
                    <table name="MUIScreen" uplink="(NodeID) = (NodeID)">
                        <table name="MUIPinnedScreen" uplink="(NodeID, WorkspaceID) = (NodeID, WorkspaceID)" />
                    </table>
                    <table name="MUITile" uplink="(ScreenID) = (ScreenID)" />
                </table>
                <table name="SiteMap" uplink="(Name) = (Url)" recursion="(NodeID) = (ParentID)" linkname="toDesignByName">
                    <table name="ListEntryPoint" uplink="(ScreenID) = (ListScreenID)" />
                    <table name="FilterHeader" uplink="(ScreenID) = (ScreenID)">
                        <table name="FilterRow" uplink="(FilterID) = (FilterID)" />
                        <table name="PivotTable" uplink="(RefNoteID) = (NoteID)">
                            <table name="PivotField" uplink="(ScreenID, PivotTableID) = (ScreenID, PivotTableID)" />
                        </table>
                        <table name="Note" uplink="(NoteID) = (NoteID)" />
                    </table>
                    <table name="MUIScreen" uplink="(NodeID) = (NodeID)">
                        <table name="MUIPinnedScreen" uplink="(NodeID, WorkspaceID) = (NodeID, WorkspaceID)" />
                    </table>
                    <table name="MUITile" uplink="(ScreenID) = (ScreenID)" />
                </table>
                <table name="SiteMap" uplink="(PrimaryScreenIDNew) = (ScreenID)" recursion="(NodeID) = (ParentID)" linkname="to1Screen">
                    <table name="ListEntryPoint" uplink="(ScreenID) = (ListScreenID)" />
                    <table name="FilterHeader" uplink="(ScreenID) = (ScreenID)">
                        <table name="FilterRow" uplink="(FilterID) = (FilterID)" />
                        <table name="PivotTable" uplink="(RefNoteID) = (NoteID)">
                            <table name="PivotField" uplink="(ScreenID, PivotTableID) = (ScreenID, PivotTableID)" />
                        </table>
                        <table name="Note" uplink="(NoteID) = (NoteID)" />
                    </table>
                    <table name="MUIScreen" uplink="(NodeID) = (NodeID)">
                        <table name="MUIPinnedScreen" uplink="(NodeID, WorkspaceID) = (NodeID, WorkspaceID)" />
                    </table>
                    <table name="MUITile" uplink="(ScreenID) = (ScreenID)" />
                </table>
                <table name="Note" uplink="(NoteID) = (NoteID)" />
            </table>
            <table name="MUIWorkspace">
                <table name="MUIFavoriteWorkspace" uplink="(WorkspaceID) = (WorkspaceID)" />
            </table>
            <table name="MUISubcategory" />
            <table name="MUIArea" />
        </layout>
        <data>
            <GIDesign>
                <row DesignID="f7069dfb-2aac-433f-828f-29fc8d32f9dc" Name="B2B-IN-ItemInventory-Synnex" FilterColCount="3" PageSize="0" NewRecordCreationEnabled="0" MassDeleteEnabled="0" AutoConfirmDelete="0" MassRecordsUpdateEnabled="0" MassActionsOnRecordsEnabled="0" ExposeViaOData="0" ExposeViaMobile="0">
                    <GITable Alias="RawPart" Name="PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem">
                        <GIRelation LineNbr="4" ChildTable="INLocationStatus" IsActive="1" JoinType="I">
                            <GIOn LineNbr="4" ParentField="inventoryID" Condition="E " ChildField="inventoryID" Operation="A" />
                        </GIRelation>
                    </GITable>
                    <GITable Alias="INLocationStatus" Name="PX.Objects.IN.INLocationStatus">
                        <GIRelation LineNbr="5" ChildTable="INLocation" IsActive="1" JoinType="I">
                            <GIOn LineNbr="5" ParentField="locationID" Condition="E " ChildField="locationID" Operation="A" />
                        </GIRelation>
                        <GIResult LineNbr="3" SortOrder="3" IsActive="1" Field="qtyAvail" SchemaField="INLocationStatus.QtyAvail" IsVisible="1" DefaultNav="1" QuickFilter="0" FastFilter="1" RowID="b684871b-4807-4d66-91db-cec612910c9c" />
                    </GITable>
                    <GITable Alias="INLocation" Name="PX.Objects.IN.INLocation" />
                    <GITable Alias="INKitSpecStkDet" Name="PX.Objects.IN.INKitSpecStkDet">
                        <GIRelation LineNbr="3" ChildTable="RawPart" IsActive="1" JoinType="I">
                            <GIOn LineNbr="3" ParentField="compInventoryID" Condition="E " ChildField="inventoryID" Operation="A" />
                        </GIRelation>
                    </GITable>
                    <GITable Alias="INKitSpecHdr" Name="PX.Objects.IN.INKitSpecHdr">
                        <GIRelation LineNbr="2" ChildTable="INKitSpecStkDet" IsActive="1" JoinType="I">
                            <GIOn LineNbr="2" ParentField="kitInventoryID" Condition="E " ChildField="kitInventoryID" Operation="A" />
                        </GIRelation>
                        <GIRelation LineNbr="1" ChildTable="FinishedPart" IsActive="1" JoinType="I">
                            <GIOn LineNbr="1" ParentField="KitInventoryID" Condition="E " ChildField="InventoryID" Operation="A" />
                        </GIRelation>
                    </GITable>
                    <GITable Alias="INItemXRef" Name="PX.Objects.IN.INItemXRef">
                        <GIResult LineNbr="4" SortOrder="4" IsActive="1" Field="alternateID" SchemaField="INItemXRef.AlternateID" IsVisible="1" DefaultNav="1" QuickFilter="0" FastFilter="1" RowID="d49abd75-3796-4245-9920-d55d68d2dcf8" />
                    </GITable>
                    <GITable Alias="FinishedPart" Name="PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem">
                        <GIRelation LineNbr="6" ChildTable="INItemXRef" IsActive="1" JoinType="I">
                            <GIOn LineNbr="6" ParentField="inventoryID" Condition="E " ChildField="inventoryID" Operation="A" />
                        </GIRelation>
                        <GIResult LineNbr="2" SortOrder="2" IsActive="1" Field="descr" SchemaField="FinishedPart.Descr" IsVisible="1" DefaultNav="1" QuickFilter="0" FastFilter="1" RowID="cf77c143-839f-426a-a99c-9eea30fa1814" />
                        <GIResult LineNbr="1" SortOrder="1" IsActive="1" Field="InventoryCD" SchemaField="FinishedPart.InventoryCD" IsVisible="1" DefaultNav="1" QuickFilter="0" FastFilter="1" RowID="69cdb4da-c09e-4a67-a235-ff865aa8ff4e" />
                    </GITable>
                    <GIWhere LineNbr="5" IsActive="1" DataFieldName="FinishedPart.itemStatus" Condition="E " IsExpression="1" Value1="NP" CloseBrackets=")        " Operation="A" />
                    <GIWhere LineNbr="4" IsActive="1" OpenBrackets="(        " DataFieldName="FinishedPart.itemStatus" Condition="E " IsExpression="1" Value1="AC" Operation="O" />
                    <GIWhere LineNbr="3" IsActive="1" DataFieldName="INItemXRef.bAccountID" Condition="E " IsExpression="0" Value1="SYNNE01" Operation="A" />
                    <GIWhere LineNbr="2" IsActive="1" DataFieldName="INLocation.locationCD" Condition="E " IsExpression="0" Value1="IOMAIN" Operation="A" />
                    <GIWhere LineNbr="1" IsActive="1" DataFieldName="INKitSpecStkDet.dfltCompQty" Condition="E " IsExpression="0" Value1="1.0" Operation="A" />
                    <SiteMap linkname="toDesignById">
                        <row Position="28" Title="IN-ItemInventory" Url="~/GenericInquiry/GenericInquiry.aspx?id=f7069dfb-2aac-433f-828f-29fc8d32f9dc" Expanded="0" IsFolder="0" ScreenID="B2GI0053" NodeID="968db91a-9cd3-4b04-87f2-15bd15d0bb8b" ParentID="e3e41d8f-4d7c-4e76-ae19-8faca25d7be7">
                            <SiteMap Position="828.75" Title="Hidden GIs for Webservice Endpoints" Expanded="1" IsFolder="0" NodeID="e3e41d8f-4d7c-4e76-ae19-8faca25d7be7">
                                <SiteMap Position="71" Title="Hidden" Url="~/Frames/Default.aspx" Expanded="0" IsFolder="0" ScreenID="HD000000" NodeID="84351bc9-bf6c-48b5-9dea-f8207283b64a">
                                    <SiteMap Position="0" Title="Acumatica Company" Url="~/Frames/Default.aspx" Expanded="0" IsFolder="0" ScreenID="00000000" NodeID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />
                                </SiteMap>
                            </SiteMap>
                        </row>
                    </SiteMap>
                </row>
            </GIDesign>
        </data>
    </data-set>
</GenericInquiryScreen>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand of your message you are probably using the Contract based API, though I am not sure if it is the SOAP or the REST version.

If you are using Generic Inquiries(GI), then in order to retrieve the data properly you should be using the PUT method instead of the GET.

Here is the the help page that is showing more detailed information about this.

REST : https://help-2018r2.acumatica.com/(W(5))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=6340cff3-4732-4231-9e42-5d1e5e65b5dd

The same procedure can be done with the SOAP version.